# Can and how to run mutual information testing in R on a pair of samples from a normal distribution?

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to ask for an example calculating the mutual information of two samples selected from a standard normal distribution in R, because so far all the posts I have found are about discrete variables. This includes the documentation for the package [entropy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/entropy/entropy.pdf):

```
# load entropy library
library("entropy")
# joint distribution of two discrete variables
freqs2d = rbind( c(0.2, 0.1, 0.15), c(0.1, 0.2, 0.25) )
# corresponding mutual information
mi.plugin(freqs2d)
# MI computed via entropy
H1 = entropy.plugin(rowSums(freqs2d))
H2 = entropy.plugin(colSums(freqs2d))
H12 = entropy.plugin(freqs2d)
H1+H2-H12
# and corresponding (half) chi-squared divergence of independence
0.5*chi2indep.plugin(freqs2d)
```

The pdf of the normal distribution is called for, but does the function call for discretization, for example binning the values in the samples?

Mutual information may just make reference to the random variable, and not a sample, but then it wouldn't really be as versatile as the correlation.

Comment: Entropy and MI are defined as functions of probability distributions, which are integrals for continuous variables and summations for discrete. Calculating MI for sample data requires estimating the whole distribution somewhere along the way -- either you have to do that, or the package is doing it for you. Binning is one way to estimate a distribution; there are many other possibilities, e.g. kernel densities or mixtures of Gaussians or anything. One has to hope that the calculated values are not too sensitive to the distribution estimate, because you can't get around having to do it.

Comment: @RobertDodier Your comment is very helpful. To some extent I saw this coming, but I'm trying to gauge what some people who casually drop MI as an alternative to correlation have in mind - in applications one deals with datasets, so I thought that perhaps a way around that was to assume normality (ha ha ha) and then take if form there with binning, or whatever...

Comment: I think we're pretty much on the same page, but just to be clear, binning is what one does when there is no assumption about the parametric form of the distribution -- if one assumes a specific distribution, such as Gaussian, one can work out the MI exactly (under that assumption). I seem to recall MI = some simple function of the correlation coefficient, for a two-dimensional Gaussian distribution.